# SQLite query and update error in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, insert-update

I'm new in Android. I'm trying to update the table in my first Application using SQLite. But when ı looked to the table from SQLite Manager ı saw that the table didn't updated. I couldn't find where the problem is?

```
public void EntryHesapla(int yilsql, String aysql,int digerTaksitlersql,
            int digersql,int maasSelosql,int maasHilalsql,int digerGelirlersql,
            int toplamHarcamasql,int toplamGelirsql,int eldeKalansql) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(C_YIL, yilsql);
        cv.put(C_AY, aysql);
        cv.put(C_DIGERTAKSITLER, digerTaksitlersql);
        cv.put(C_DIGER, digersql);
        cv.put(C_MAASSELO, maasSelosql);
        cv.put(C_MAASHILAL, maasHilalsql);
        cv.put(C_DIGERGELIRLER, digerGelirlersql);
        cv.put(C_TOPLAMHARCAMA, toplamHarcamasql);
        cv.put(C_TOPLAMGELIR, toplamGelirsql);
        cv.put(C_ELDEKALAN, eldeKalansql);

        String[] selectionArgs=new String[]{yilsql+"", aysql};
        String entryHesaplaSQL="SELECT c_id FROM harcamalar WHERE "+C_YIL+"= ? AND "+C_AY+"= ?";
        Cursor cursor=ourDatabase.rawQuery(entryHesaplaSQL, selectionArgs);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        cursor.moveToPosition(cursor.getCount() - 1);
        int index=cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(C_ID));
        if(index>=0)
                ourDatabase.update(DB_TABLE, cv, C_ID+"="+index, null);
        else ourDatabase.insert(DB_TABLE, null, cv);

    }
```

Comment: you should test the return value of update and insert

Comment: are u closing your database after insertion?

Comment: how will ı test return values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cursor.getColumnIndex(C_ID);
```

returns the column index for the C_ID column in your query. It is 0, as there is only 1 column in your query.

If you want the value for this column, you need to call `getInt(index)` (see [getColumnIndex](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getColumnIndex%28java.lang.String%29) for further details.)

Comment: This is the perfect one. Its all on your query selection.